# How to convert AudioBuffer to data?

Tags: ios, swift

i want to convert unsafemutablepointer to data, here is my sample code

```
let u8ptr: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8> = buffer.mData!.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)
```

I am trying to convert AudioBuffer to NSData or Data.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you mean `Data`, you need the byte size of the data. If you are planning to convert `AudioBuffer` to `Data`, you should better explicitly represent it in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When working with `AudioBuffer`, the byte size of the data is given int the property `mDataByteSize`. And when creating a `Data`, you have no need to convert the pointer type using `assumingMemoryBound`.

```
let data = Data(bytes: buffer.mData!, count: Int(buffer.mDataByteSize))
```